# Passing to the supremum of a sequence of random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Suppose you have a sequence of positive, integrable and identically distributed random variables $X_n$ $n\geq 1$ and let $S_n=\sum_{i=1}^n X_n$. By the monotone convergence theorem, $$ \lim_{M\to \infty} E\left[\frac{S_n}{n} \cdot \mathbb{1}_{\frac{S_n}{n} \leq M}\right] = E[S_n] $$ for each $n$. This implies $$ \lim_{M\to \infty} E\left[\frac{S_n}{n} \cdot \mathbb{1}_{\frac{S_n}{n} \gt M}\right] = 0 $$
Is it then also true that $$\lim_{M\to \infty} \sup_{n \geq 1} E\left[\frac{S_n}{n} \cdot \mathbb{1}_{\frac{S_n}{n} \gt M}\right] = 0 ?$$
If so, why?

Answer (score 0):

Since $X_i$ are iid and $\chi_M = 1_{\{\frac{S_n}{n} > M\}}$ is symmetric with respect to $X_1, \dots, X_n$, the random variables $Y_i = X_i\chi_M$ are integrable and identically distributed and $E[Y_1] = E[Y_i]$ for all $i=1,,\dots,n$. Thus,
$$E\left[\frac{S_n}{n} \chi_M\right] = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n E\left[X_i\chi_M\right] = E[X_1 \chi_M].$$
The supremum is therefore vacuous and the claim holds by integrability of $X_1$ and the monotone convergence theorem.

Comment: Does it change your reasoning that they are not independent, but only identically distributed?